# Can you search for and remove specific lines with Apache error_log?

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

I know I am able to search for particular **keywords** in my Apache error_log file by using the grep command:

```
# grep "favicon.ico" error_log
```

I am curious though if it is possible to delete/remove any and all lines which contain specific keywords from a file.

I know this won't work but the idea is:

```
rm -r -f grep "favicon.ico" error_log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -i '/favicon.ico/d' error_log
```

But you can get rid of this error appearing in Apache error log by creating an empty `favicon.ico` file in document root or putting the following in the `httpd.conf` file:

```
Redirect 404 /favicon.ico

<Location /favicon.ico>
    ErrorDocument 404 "No favicon"
</Location>
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I did come across the last bit you added but giving several 404 errors seems like it would be bad for page ranking.